# Laravel return the page on any address except from routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a list of routes for my Laravel application. Now, I want to return the same page as is returned on `/` for all routes that are not listed. I.e.

```
/hello/world <-> binded to "Hello world" page
/blah/blah <-> binded to "Blah Blah" p
```

Now, no matter what user requests (GET) and how many slashes in the request are (`/asdfda/sadfasdf/asdfasdf`, `eafsadfsda`, `asdfadsfasd/adsfsdaf`), I want to return the same page. I do not want it to be 404 though, as I want to keep that a legal route.

---

I tried

```
Route::get('{all?}', [
    'as' => 'spa.index',
    'uses' => 'SPAController@index',
]);
```

But that works only if there are no slashes.

---

Do someone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found solution by myself. I'll keep the question for future generations. This will return the same page no matter what route user requests

```
Route::get('{all?}', [
    'as' => 'spa.index',
    'uses' => 'SPAController@index',
])->where('all', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('/{foo}/{bar}', [
   'as' => 'spa.index',
   'uses' => 'SPAController@index',
]);
```

and in SPAController and action index add:

```
public function index($foo,$bar){
     return view($foo.' '.$bar);
}
```